# Homesick with bash-it as submodule

Tags: git, github, dotfiles, bash-it

I'm using [Homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) to maintain my *dotfiles* on Github. In addition to this, I'm also using the fabulous [bash-it](https://github.com/revans/bash-it) for general bash functionality and plugins. My dotfile configuration is kept in one Github repo as a *homesick castle*, while my bash-it fork is kept in a separate [Github repo](https://github.com/nwinkler/bash-it).

When I want to set up a new machine, I first need to clone my bash-it repo (`git clone ...`), and then set up homesick and clone my dotfiles repo from there (`homesick clone nwinkler/dotfiles`).

Is there a way to make this easier, i.e. maintain my bash-it repo either as a second homesick castle, or even better as a submodule of my dotfiles castle? Ideally, I would be able to set up my dotfiles castle and bash-it with just one command.

Could (or should) I leverage Git submodules for this? Or is there a better way?